# When appending items dynamically, masonry does not layout them out

Tags: javascript, html, angular, jquery-masonry, masonry

I am using a Masonry JavaScript grid layout library https://masonry.desandro.com/. I have an issue when appending new items to the grid directly from the DOM using Angular *ngfor which iterate through an a array as follows:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height{{i}}" *ngFor="let i of array">
   {{i}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Because I am not appending them using the "appended masonry method", masonry does not layout them out. The array is getting new elements every time a user scroll down. So a JavaScript method is called:

```
onScrollDown() {
 // add another 20 items
 this.sum += 20;
 for (let i = start; i < this.sum; ++i) {
     this.array.push(i);  }
 }
```

When the array get more elements, it automatically creates new html items. So i need to find the way masonry layout them out again after the new items are being created. I tried  calling $grid.masonry('layout') after the elements have being added to the array in the OnScrollMethod but it did not work. 
I am trying $('.grid').masonry('reloadItems') as well, but calling this method the new items are overlapping the previous ones.

I would appreciate any help.

Update:

I am initializing masonry using my angular initialize component method as follows:

```
  ngOnInit() {
  this.$grid = jQuery('.grid').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: 384,
    gutter: 24
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED

You might try `reloadItems`. If your loading images, use [imagesLoaded.js](https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js) to avoid overlaps:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.$grid = jQuery('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
jQuery('.grid').masonry({
// options
itemSelector: '.grid-item',
columnWidth: 384,
gutter: 24
});
});


onScrollDown() {
// add another 20 items
this.sum += 20;
for (let i = start; i < this.sum; ++i) {
 this.array.push(i);  }
jQuery('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
jQuery('.grid').masonry('reloadItems');
});
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @Macsupport. I tried $('.grid').masonry('reloadItems') and it seems to run masonry but now it is ovelapping the new items on the top of the previous ones.  I am initializing masonry using my angular initialize component method. See the update in the question. Any idea how Can i stop that overlapping behavior?

Comment: If you are loading images, then you need to use  [imagesloaded.js](https://imagesloaded.desandro.com) to avoid the overlap.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a lot of years since I had to do this, but basically:

Masonry runs a lot of JS, in order to figure out optimal bin-packing for the elements you are creating.
That means that it hard-codes a lot of style information on each "card" inside of your area, and after it calculates it, it sets it.
If you use Masonry to add new "cards" to that view, then it will continue to update the view, and change the layout and the sizes of those cards.
If you don't use the Masonry instance you had before (you use the element, not the Masonry object), then Masonry doesn't have a way to track the changes. At that point, you either have to add them to the DOM and then add them to the object, through `addItems`, and THEN call `layout()` (or `masonry()`)... or you have to rewrap the DOM element in Masonry again, now that the element has updated.

This might have changed, but I doubt it.

There are things you could do by writing angular directives, I guess, but the cheap and cheerful way of accomplishing this would be to save the instance of your component's element (or the element that controller is bound to... whatever), and also save the reference to the Masonry view you made, and on update, add all of the items, and call layout again...
...or just, on each render, make a new Masonry view, using your root element.
PS: make sure to load a lot of new elements at once, because if you're just loading 3 at a time it'll be messy...
...also, make sure you pre-load the images in the elements, because if the images load afterwards your Masonry layout is going to get very, very messy.

Comment: Thanks @Norguard. it seems a bit complex this approach. Let me see if i can digest it and try it.

Comment: @D.B it's complex because you have a lot going on, whether you know it or not. The way Angular works, and the way Masonry works don't go well together, without doing your own work in one way or another, or finding (/making) some library that does.
Masonry doesn't work well if you haven't already loaded those images (your cards are going to appear collapsed, or drawn over top of one another, because when Masonry ran, the size of the images was (0px,0px). It doesn't magically keep track of all size changes to all cards; you have to do that, and tell it when to load more items, or render again.

Comment: @D.B because of this, you have to call Masonry after angular has drawn (in case it added more items), AND after you load all/each image(s). If you miss any step, you will have a Masonry bug. That's not complicated. It's just complex.

Answer (score 0):

I used masonry-layout in Vue.js and had the same problem. The way that solved my issue is:

```
onScrollDown() {
  // ...
  // after add another 20 items
  this.msnry.reloadItems();
  this.msnry.layout();
 }
```

That this.msnry is my masonry-layout instance.